# Starting MySQL fails after upgrading to MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, debian, database

While setting up a test server for the development of a Magento plugin, I ran into the requirement of MySQL 5.6. I was already using MySQL 5.5 so running `apt-get install mysql-server-5.6` should have done the trick. Upon finishing the installation, this happened:

```
[....] Starting MySQL database server: mysqldNo directory, logging in with HOME=/
[FAIL. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-22) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The MySQL server won't start anymore. I've tried `service mysql start` but the same thing happens. Any suggestions? I'm running Debian 7.

Thanks in advance,
Roemer Bakker

Comment: @Jos I have tried the solution provided in that question but it did not work.

Comment: Is `mysql` owner of `/var/lib/mysql`?

Comment: @Jos Yup! This is from `ls -l /var/lib`: `drwx------ 31 mysql   mysql   4096 Jun 21 12:29 mysql`

Comment: I'm not sure the "No Directory" message is the actual error that causes the "FAIL" though. Is there anything interesting in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` or in `journalctl -u mysql`?

Comment: @Jos the log is completely empty and I don't have journalctl installed :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41446/discussion-between-jos-and-roemer-bakker).

Comment: Sorry, you need to have more rep points to chat. Anyway: so you're not on a `systemd` system then. Look in `/var/log/upstart/` to see if there is any mention of `mysql`  service errors.